# A to L lower and M to Z uppercase

Tags: python, string, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to set some condition on string. 
Condition is if character is A to L then lower it. 
if character is M to Z uppercase it.
 **Following is Code**

```
def fun_exercise_6(word):
  low = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']
  up = ['m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
  y_res = ''
  for ch in word.lower():
    for i in low:
      if ch == i:
        y_res = y_res+''+ch.lower()
    for i in up:
      if ch == i:
        y_res = y_res+''+ch.upper()
  return y_res

print(fun_exercise_6("boat"))
```

Is there any better approach to this problem ?

Comment: I'm not fluent in python, but it's going to be something simple like `if ch >= 'm'`  Then you don't need the two inside `for` loops or the `low` & `up` collections at all.

Comment: Thankyou so much. I never thought like this. never knew it can work like number.
Thankyou Again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the above algorithm will run in quadratic time, so that means that for larger strings, this will take some time. Furthermore you also loop over two lists, this has, strictly speaking, no impact on the time complexity, but it slows down the program significantly.

We can use checks like `'a' <= c <= 'l'` to check if a character is between `'a'` and `'l'`. Furthermore we here do not need to append characters to the list ourselves, we can use `''.join(..)` for that. For example:

```
def fun_exercise_6(word):
    return ''.join(
        c.lower() if 'a' <= c.lower() <= 'l' else c.upper() for c in word
    )
```

Here we construct a generator that emits characters (lowercase for characters in the `'a'` to `'l'` and `'A'` to `'L'` range, and uppercase otherwise). We join these charaters then together.

Comment: Thankyou so much for taking your time to answer this title question. :)
I got it we can use > and < for alphabets too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Short method

```
alphabet = []
# Create the alphabet
for letter in range(97,123):
    alphabet.append(chr(letter))
# Loop, and enumerate for position being A-L, then M-Z
for num,i in enumerate(alphabet):
  if num < 12:
    print(i)
  else:
    # Turn to upper case if it's m-z
    i = i.upper()
    print(i)
```